# Search options with updating on screen query

Tags: jquery

I am currently making a search field for my website, it has multiple options and the main feature I am struggling with is that when a user starts selecting data to search for it echos out the search query they want to perform.

Here is an image of what I am trying to achieve.

http://i4.minus.com/jbluKDVCTV1HKh.png

So when a user starts picking options from the list, it updates in the bottom right what the user is aiming to search for. Some categorys must allow multiple selections, for example the user might want to search for Type D and A in Blue by Make C.

What I have done so far is that the search query is split up into three parts (Where the data will be inputted) and every time a user clicks an option it first looks to see if there is an a tag with the value of the option being selected, but it doesn't scale well.

How would you tackle implementing something like this? At the moment my way feels a bit clunky.

Any questions are welcomed as I would like to find a good way of doing this and moving on from it! Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like what you are doing is working. What is your question?

Comment: The code to actually make it work is very long and I was seeing if there is a better way of doing it. It only just about works.

Comment: Without seeing your code, no one will be able to tell if you are doing it in the most concise way possible. You might already be doing it in the best manner. Make a JSFiddle or something.

Comment: It would take too long to carve it out of the project and get it working in a fiddle. How would you do it?

Comment: So, it would take YOU too long to show what you've done, but you want me to just develop something from scratch for you? This is not the purpose of the site my friend.

Comment: I will take a wild guess and say you are much more advanced than I at jQuery (Why else would you be searching for questions for the topic) so I would say what takes me hours would take you a lot shorter, so yes. And I'm not asking you to make it for me, I wouldn't learn that way, I'm asking how you would do it. Which is what I thought this website was for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `jsfiddle` working example of what I think you're trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/b446B/

I've created 3 different cases:
- required class, for the field that needs to be in the end query
- multiple class, for field that allows for multiple selection
- without the above, where a singular selection is needed

The labels can be different from the fields, that's why I'm storing them in the rel attribute.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you using your time developing an actual answer *nudge* @Leeish